# Can hypervisors (HyperV, Virtualbox...) offer any early microcomputer session? I can have an Debian 4 session but not an Oric one

Tags: virtual-machine

It's a recreational question, but a question whatever.

I was searching for *Vagrant* boxes of early operating systems such as *Debian 4*, trying to go as far in the past than the *Oric* computer I had before.

*Debian 4* is available as a *Vagrant* box or ISO image. But for *Oric* and early microcomputers: no boxes or images ready for *Vagrant*/*Virtualbox*/*HyperV*.

On a Linux computer, what are the limits that an hypervisor cannot cross, that makes it unable to emulate a vintage micro-computer?

Is it that it will never be able to emulate a 6502 CPU, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Hypervisors aren’t emulators, so no, KVM, VirtualBox, Hyper-V won’t ever emulate a 6502. [Hypervisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) allows multiple operating systems to run in parallel on a computer, by effectively partitioning that computer’s resources, including its CPU; but they don’t change the nature of the core computer hardware, so a hypervisor running on x86 will only run x86 software.

You can of course run an emulator inside a hypervisor, so you can prepare an image that will provide an emulated environment.

Answer (score 1):

There's literally thousands of emulators for smaller systems! Especially for the 6502, there's a load. It's just not of something usually called "hypervisor" to emulate something that's not close to an application processor; that's the job of what's usually called an "emulator".

You can try retroarch, which is a frontend to many emulators, and has atari and NES and a lot of other emulators available.

Especially the 6502 is emulated in game console emulators, e.g., for the original 8-bit Atari, the Atari 2600, the NES, Commodore 64 and the BBC Micro, and many more. There's also some Oric emulators, but I've not tried a single one of these. (I'd probably run an Atari emulator in retroarch, and try to run Atoric, an Oric emulator for Atari computers, within that.)

Comment: So why can't I see a single Vagrant box or virtualbox image for my Oric? Is its 6502 processor responsible?

Comment: Because vagrant and virtualbox are not emulators, but hypervisors, and what you need is an emulator